# Does this 中国是 。。轮番上市 mean 'flooding the market'?

Tags: meaning

The 是 here without a following 的 seems a bit odd.

中国目前是新车和降价车轮番上市，使准备买车的消费者不知如何选择。

I see that 轮番 means 'one after another' but I get the sense of 'flooding the market'. Is that correct?

中国目前是新车和降价车轮番上市，

At present the Chinese car market is flooded with new, low priced cars,

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A decent translation for `轮番上市` would be `flooding the market`.

> 中国目前是新车和降价车轮番上市，

should probably be translated instead as:

> At present the Chinese car market is being flooded with both new and low priced cars,

Comment: Thanks. On that water theme, you could also say 'awash with new, low priced cars'

Comment: Haha, that's decent too.